# Don't understand why Conditional "OR" operator not working for me?

Tags: java

Am doing this online exercise and one question is:

> We'll say that a number is "teen" if it is in the range 13..19
>      inclusive. Given 2 int values, return true if one or the other is
>      teen, but not both

So I should return true if one of the int values that it passes into my method is in the range of 13 and 19 but return false if both are in the range; This is the code I wrote:

```
 public boolean loneTeen(int a, int b) {
  if ( a >= 13 && a <= 19 || b >= 13 && b <= 19 )
  return true;
  else
  return false;
}
```

basically if integer a is between 13 and 19 inclusive or if integer b is between 13 and 19 inclusive I return true otherwise I return false. When I test this it works except If I pass in 13 and 13 for integer a and b, I get true instead of false. My question is I've looked up the conditional "OR(||)" operator and it says that:

- if the first operand determines the overall value for the condition, then the second operand is not evaluated.

So when I use "Or" operator  like my code above doesn't it mean if a is in the range return true or if b is in the range return true but if both are in the range return false? what is the differance between using

- `if ( a >= 13 && a <= 19 || b >= 13 && b <= 19 )`
  and
- `if ( a >= 13 && a <= 19 && b >= 13 && b <= 19 )`
  Why isn't it returning false if both values passed in are in the range?

Comment: It's a bad thing that the || operator won't evaluate both conditions when the first is true: You *need* to check both when the first is true because, in that case, you must ensure that the second is false.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically all you want is for *exactly one* of the values `isTeen(a)` and `isTeen(b)` to be true, so use [XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or):

```
if ((a >= 13 && a <= 19) ^ (b >= 13 && b <= 19))
```

- If you replace `^` with `||`, you allow for the possibility of *both* `a` and `b` being teen numbers.
- If you replace `^` with `&&`, you are essentially saying that you always want both `a` and `b` to be teen numbers.

Neither of these are what you want. XOR, on the other hand, works for your problem perfectly.

Comment: Thanks, that puts in whole new perspective

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the lack of braces.

Ideally you would write something like this:

```
public boolean isPersonTeen(int a) {
  if ( a >= 13 && a <= 19)
      return true;
  // If you came here means the condition failed.
  return false;
}
```

Now you can just check XOR

```
 isPersonTeen(a) ^ isPersonTeen(b)
```

Hth!

Answer (score 0):

The || (or) operator returns true if at least one of the parts is true. Now if both parts are true, is at least one of the parts true? The answer is yes. That's why when the first part is evaluated as true, it's unnecessary to check the other part.

What you're looking for is the exclusive or (^). This operator will return true if only one of the parts is true. So, to get the results you want, all you need to do is to replace || for ^, like so:

```
    public boolean loneTeen(int a, int b) {
        if ( (a >= 13 && a <= 19) ^ (b >= 13 && b <= 19) )
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Edit: Parentheses inside the if statement added after the discussion with David Wallace.

Comment: You could use some more parentheses to make this correct.  It's wrong as it stands because `^` is higher than `&&` in the order of operations.

Comment: Actually, even though ^ has a higher precedence order than &&, in this situation it's obvious that the ^ operation cannot return a value until both && operations have been performed and returned theirs values, because it (^) needs the two sides values to return its answer.
So my code, the way it is, works just fine. Try and run it. Parentheses could be used for readability only, but they would have no effect on the result.

Comment: No, you are incorrect.  Suppose `a=10` and `b=15`.  Then the correct answer is `(a >= 13 && a <= 19) ^ (b >= 13 && b <= 19)` which is `(false && true) ^ (true && true)`, which is `true`.  But  your answer is `a >= 13 && a <= 19 ^ b >= 13 && b <= 19` which is `false && true ^ true && false`, which is `false && false && false` (because `^` is evaluated before `&&`) which is `false`.  Please try it for yourself if you don't believe me; and then after you've tried it, please consider _either_ deleting your answer _or_ inserting the required parentheses.

Comment: Oh, now I see where I had it wrong. Thanks for the insight.